# Firefox: "TypeError: localStorage is null"

Tags: html, firefox, local-storage

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/localstorage.html

When I view that website in IE or Chrome, add data, hit the save button, go to another website and then go back to that one, the data is still there.  But in Firefox it isn't.  The error log has a "TypeError: localStorage is null" message in it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of FireFox?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of Firefox and that DOM storage is not disabled. http://webdevwonders.com/clear-dom-storage/

Comment: DOM storage was apparently disabled.  Weird.  Thanks!!

Comment: Great! I added the anser in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ensure that you are using the latest version of Firefox.

If you are using the latest version of Firefox and it still does not work then ensure DOM Storage is enabled.

Type `about:config` in your address bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to view your internal browser settings.

Scroll down to `dom.storage.enabled`, if it is disabled then right click on it and hit `Toggle` to enable the DOM Storage.

Source: http://webdevwonders.com/clear-dom-storage/